# How to create kaleidoscope images like default avatars here at SO?

Tags: php, image

How can I create kaleidoscope images like default avatars here at SO, using PHP?

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure the default generated images are actually generated by gravatar, more about that here: http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/

According to them, they use the "identicon" which is actually based on the email.

http://scott.sherrillmix.com/blog/blogger/wp_identicon/

You can take a look at that code and see how it's generated :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Imagemagick binding to php.
Here are some distortion functions: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/
And here is kaleidoscope script: http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/kaleidoscope/index.php

You can combine distortions and kaleidoscope to get nice pictures.

E.g. something like this (bash, not php):

```
$ mkkal='dx=i-50; dy=j-50; rad=hypot(dx,dy); tt=mod((atan2(dy,dx)+6.28319+0)*5/(6.28319),1.0); ang=2*(tt<0.5?tt:1-tt); u.p{50+rad*cos(ang),50+rad*sin(ang)}'
$ convert -size 100x100 pattern:checkerboard -distort Barrel '-0.2 -3.0 0.2 1.3' -fx "$mkkal" tile.png
$ display tile.png
```

Try different args to Barrel or different distortion methods to get more interesting results.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any experience with GD.

Answer (score 0):

They are created by [gravatar.com](http://gravatar.com/)

Examplse: http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/78fg67b5c2c25634fgadd727f6b08?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG